# Gnome 3 loses focus after closing all open windows

Tags: gnome, keyboard, mouse, workspaces, focus

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, which I have had for a long time. On this computer I've installed both XFCE4 and Gnome 3, and I'm currently using Gnome 3 Fallback.

Recently I've been having a weird problem. When I close all open windows in a given workspace (be it with mouse, alt-f4 or other key-combinations), everything loses focus and the keyboard doesn't work anymore. I need to click anywhere on the desktop for these things to start working again.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I have that problem after installing 14.04. I didn't realize until your post that it was only the last window closing, so thanks for your post.  I'm going to test it on a clean login.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

I kinda solve that changing focus mode:

1. tweak tool
2. Windows
3. Windows focus mode

I've set it to "Sloppy" (also mouse works).

When I close all the windows the focus goes to the one under the mouse, and everything goes well :-)